# MS Word not creating new bullets when hitting return

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm experiencing a strange error that I am not familiar with.

- Can auto create bullet list with *
- Indenting and un-indenting with TAB works
- Automatic bulleted lists is selected in AutoCorrect options
- Performing a Repair of Microsoft office in Programs and Features does nothing

---

For those who run into this in the future try forcing Word to rebuild the default style.

- Go to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
- Change the name of the Normal.dotm (deleting it shouldn't cause problems) then open a new word document.

Word will rebuild the default styles and should resolve the problem... probably ;)

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with bulletin lists created by clicking the button on the file tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulleted lists are probably saved as a Style that specifies the following paragraph is formatted as "Normal" or a non-bulleted paragraph style.

Find the list in the Style gallery, right click, select modify, and check the drop-down menu for "Style for the following paragraph."

Comment: -_- Thanks for the follow up. Totally brain farted on this.